# What are "/run/lock" and "/run/shm" used for?

Tags: mount, system, partitioning

I just want to know where and how `/run/lock` and `/run/shm` can help our PC .

```
$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              56G   13G   41G  24% /
udev                  983M  4.0K  983M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 396M  840K  395M   1% /run
none                  5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none                  990M  164K  990M   0% /run/shm
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

> Short answer: they store temporary system files, including device locks and memory segments shared between different processes. Don't worry, they usually use a *fraction* of their "size" shown by `df`

1. **`/run` is, in general, a temporary filesystem (tmpfs) residing in RAM** (aka "ramdisk"); its meant for storing "temporary" system or state files which may be critical but *do not* require persistence across reboots.

   - `/run` is actually a fairly new innovation, and was added a couple of years ago to replace the multiple tmpfs's that used to be created (including `/var/lock` and `/dev/shm`) with a single unified root tmpfs.
   - The main locations `/run` [replaces are:](http://wiki.debian.org/ReleaseGoals/RunDirectory)

   ```
   /var/run → /run
   /var/lock → /run/lock
   /dev/shm → /run/shm [currently only Debian plans to do this]
   /tmp → /run/tmp [optional; currently only Debian plans to offer this]
   ```
2. **`/run/lock`** (formerly `/var/lock`) [contains lock files](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARLOCKLOCKFILES), i.e. files indicating that a shared device or other system resource is in use and containing the identity of the process (PID) using it; this allows other processes to properly coordinate access to the shared device.
3. **`/run/shm`** (formerly `/dev/shm`) is temporary world-writable shared-memory. [Strictly speaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory#Specific_implementations), it is intended as storage for programs using the POSIX Shared Memory API. It facilitates what is known as *inter-process communication* [(IPC)](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html), where different processes can share and communicate via a common memory area, which in this case is usually a normal file that is stored on a "ramdisk". Of course, it can be and has been used in other creative ways as well ;)
4. **Do not be alarmed about the size**: importantly, many people running `df -h` and knowing that `/run` is backed by RAM are shocked that their precious memory is being "wasted" by these mysterious folders. Just like the *Linux ate my RAM myth* though, this belief is incorrect.

   - The size shown is only the *maximum* that may be used
   - It defaults to 50% of physical RAM
   - Only as much shown in the *Used* column is actually in use, which in the above screenshot is less than 1 megabyte total
   - You can use the `ipcs -m` command to verify that the actual shared memory segments used match up to the `df` summary, and also see which PIDs are using them
   - Like your regular RAM, `/run` is also eventually backstopped by your swap, so if you are using `/run/shm` for "faster" compile times, keep that in mind ;)

Comment: +1. CentOS (RHEL) 7.* still use /dev/shm still now.

Comment: Thanks for a nicely formulated answer. I'd like to point out an inaccuracy, tmpfs is not really *in* RAM and tmpfs is not ramdisk or even similar to ramdisk. This is a common misconception. tmpfs might be RAM based but it's hdd backed. RAM based the same as any file on a hdd through a page cache. To use tmpfs in a hope it's much faster or that it will not wake hdd from stand-by is a common mistake.

Comment: Here's a [reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/296043/227364) for tmpfs vs ramfs.