# /run/lock and /run/shm missing

Tags: 11.10, mount, data-recovery, lock, shm

Recently I found `/run/lock` and `/run/shm` folders to be missing.

I tried to recover some files with a mounted disk, I now know that this may caused the harm. So unaware what to do, I created these directories by myself.

Now I looked up the command `df -h` and saw this output:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6             913G   69G  798G   8% /
udev                  5,9G  4,0K  5,9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 2,4G  872K  2,4G   1% /run
none                  5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none                  5,9G  2,1M  5,9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda1             915M  358M  509M  42% /boot
```

I didn't know there were such file systems, how can I mount them in again? Is this something harmful?

I also  saw that I have high I/O with my Journal `jbd2/sda6-8` always around 40%, has this something to do with this?

Comment: This should clear all your doubts: [What are “/run/lock” and “/run/shm” used for?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/169495/what-are-run-lock-and-run-shm-used-for)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/169495/what-are-run-lock-and-run-shm-used-for

Comment: @saji89 I disagree slightly. I'm perhaps biased, having written an answer, but I was approaching this as more of a "Why is their filesystem listed as none? Are they broken?" than a "what are they?"

Comment: @Oli, I feel that this particular information will better serve as a good addon to the answer already here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/169495/what-are-run-lock-and-run-shm-used-for His question was: "I didn't know there were such file systems, how can I mount them in again? Is this something harmful?". looks like the other question definitely answers that.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the link anyway! It's always good to understand what something does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `df` is getting thrown by the lack of specified device. If you look with `mount`, you'll see that the filesystem is definitely `tmpfs`.

```
$ df -h | grep run
tmpfs                          4.8G  1.4M  4.8G   1% /run
none                           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                            12G  4.9M   12G   1% /run/shm
none                           100M  8.0K  100M   1% /run/user

$ mount | grep run
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
rpc_pipefs on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
```

I would guess that because `tmpfs` is a ram-disk that you don't actually need to specify a block level object to "mount".

I would certainly welcome people correct me if that assumption is incorrect but for your case there is nothing to worry about. They're not missing, they're just mounted funny... And that just happens to be the way all my Ubuntu computers here are also set up. Panic not.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the clarification. Now I can calm down :-). Only problem left is the Journal problem, but that seems to be quite another matter now.

Comment: @DanLee Almost certainly unrelated to this. I'd start a new question about it if I were you.

Comment: Yeah you're right! That's why I didn't want to ask you more about that in this topic.