# External SSD drive Partition Scheme

Tags: ssd

I am about to install Kubuntu (principally for a marvellous KDE Plasma Desktop) on an ext SSD drive.
It is my first adventure with Linux in my life.

I will be deeply thankful for some pieces of advice, recommendation on the following.
.Many thanks in advance.

1. Is Kubuntu same spice as any ...buntu Linux? If yes I think it could be easier to find the similar guidance concerning this very special Kubuntu.

2.
I have read many Linux installation guidances and I am quite confusing about recommendations concerning a partition scheme. Almost each guru have his own configuration.
i would appreciate if someone could clearly indicate me the best practical partition scheme for my very disk.

It is a SSD 240gb one, brand new.
I would like to know what partitions do I need, well the disk, to be able to boot on any system attached to.
The idea is to use it as an everywhere personal portable system

Do I need a boot partition, home, etc. And how big?

Is there any additional setting to make to take full advantage of SSD system, any special configuration to add?

Perhaps any precise links?

once more huge thanks in advance with my kind regards.

PS

Is KDE Plasma 5.7 already activate on the most recent version of Kubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

1. It is a flavour that used KDE as a desktop. It is a totally different experience than Unity (what Ubuntu uses) or gnome.
2. well it IS a personal choice.

   > Do I need a boot partition, home, etc. And how big?

   No. You do not need it. You can mount it all with just a `/`, you can opt to mount an extra `/home/`, extra partitions for `/opt/`, `/usr/`, `/var/` (the old "server setup") if you feel like it. Like said before: it is a personal choice.

   If you want a partition scheme though ...

   - 25 Gb for `/` is more than enough and leaves plenty of room for installation of software and kernels. Don't bother with a `/boot` partition.
   - create a data partition to store all your personal data. Change `~./config/user-dirs.dirs` to change the location of your home dirs to that partition.
   - Advantage: when re-installing you can format / (and /home) without the need to worry about where your files are. During install you mount your data partition and are good to go. All you need to do is edit `~./config/user-dirs.dirs`. And a backup is basically making a copy of your data partition. Or if you like it you could set up a synch service with google drive (or something similar).

---

> Is there any additional setting to make t1o take full advantage of SSD system, any special configuration to add?

A few things come to mind:

- `fstrim` is used to clean up your ssd.
- change your fstab to put some of your partitions on "tmpfs". Have a look at https://wiki.debian.org/SSDOptimization and https://superuser.com/questions/1042215/how-to-use-tmpfs-and-ssd-for-smart-cache/1042222 for some good pointers.

Comment: I really do appreciate your prompt and exhausted response. Please let me take a couple of... hours to sleep it out. I will return for some elucidation, if you do not mind. I think my modest Linux knowledge has been overestimated. Huge thanks. And.... A swap partition/file...just a quick thought.

Comment: I have to admit that I am commence to approach the logic.
I am afraid I would have to ask you for most detailed guidance if you are so kind and patient.
I have heard of /efi partition - do I need it if yes what size, file format, if any alignment, etc?
How about a swap partition (min 4GB RAM system), or swap file?

Comment: I thought the home directory was a space for custom data and setting storage. I can see that your option is more flexible and secure in case of any restoration/reparation, upgrading.

Would you mind guide me in details on performing this operation. I have read on mapping the home directory but I cannot figure it out. I have read also on certain .config flle restoration on startup problems.
I would appreciate an clear example - let us say my custom-user partition will be named myAAdata.

Comment: What system file shall I use for any of those partitions and an what alignment? Could it be possible to share custom-user partition between Windows and Linux (ie. pictures, video, other data) - I guess the file system pays a certain role here.

If it possible I would be most obliged for as detailed guidance as possible. I am aware that could be annoying for such guru as you are.

I have to admit that the last part on SSD if far from my modest knowledge of Linux. Especially those magic charms make me enchanted. I am used to use a visual interface (I am visual in general).

Comment: I would ask you of some detailed elucidation of "tmpfs", etc.
What shall be the steps to well fulfil your precious recommendations.

My huge thank you in advance and your patience, indulgence.

Comment: @J23 size of EFI is set by the system when you create it  (so no need to worry about that). Linux use EXT. Windows use NTFS for system. "tmpfs" is a mount option set in /etc/ftsab (that one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/296038/what-is-the-difference-between-tmpfs-and-ramfs has an example)