# What creates /run/lock?

Tags: 12.04, server

I have found that it lacks `/run/lock` directory.

And I cannot find out what daemon/init script creates it.

Could you give me a hint?

Just to make it clear:

1.

```
# mount
/var/lib/vz/private/101 on / type simfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdb on /var/lib/mysql type ext4 (rw,noatime,relatime,barrier=1,data=ordered)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600,ptmxmode=000)
varrun on /run type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
```

2.

```
# ls -la /run/l*
ls: cannot access /run/l*: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I could remount it using plain old

```
mount -o remount /run/lock
```

and it's defined in `/lib/init/fstab`

Comment: You will probably need sudo to be able to that command. This answer doesn'ät answer the first question, "What creates /run/lock?" ...

Comment: @Alvar: is it better now?

Answer (score 1):

`/run/lock` used to be `/var/lock`.

It should be cleaned up or recreated during the boot process, for Ubuntu I am not sure which script does it.

However, I know for [LFS](/etc/rc.d/init.d/cleanfs) the `/etc/rc.d/init.d/cleanfs` script does the job => http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/scripts/apds12.html

Some background:

`/var/run` => `/run` is in memory filesystem (`tmpfs`) used for storing temporary system or  state files (e.g. PID, Unix socket, etc...) that do NOT require persistence across reboots.

see => [What are "/run/lock" and "/run/shm" used for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169495/what-are-run-lock-and-run-shm-used-for)

To manually create / mount

```sh
sudo mkdir -p /run
sudo chmod 755 /run
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755 tmpfs /run
```

BTW: some off-topic stuff about `tmpfs` VS `ramfs`

- tmpfs swaps out to disk but ramfs does NOT
- tmpfs has fixed size (specified) but ramfs does NOT (you can keep writing even exceeds the max size)

Comment: And what daemon creates it? My question is: it lacks on one machine, how would I fix it.

Comment: Well, I need to create it back without reboot for obvious reasons :-)

Comment: You can manually mount it anyway. Will update the answer.