# Logical sector size for physical sector size of 4096

Tags: hard-drive, performance

With many new hard drive disks the physical sector size is 4096. 
Would it be possible to make the system use a logical sector size of the same size, rather than the default logical sector size of 512?

How would you configure that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* a difference between block size and cluster-size but there is no such thing as logical sector size in ext4.

Probably you already have an `IO block` of 4096: try doing a `stat .bash_logout` in your home directory.

```
  File: ‘.bash_logout’
  Size: 220         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
```

For more info: `man mkfs.ext4`

And finally: **Stop worrying!** ext4 uses heuristics to format your drive as efficiently as possible.  ;-)

Comment: @matt: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: Indeed! good to know. Yet a certain disk command line utility does use that term.

Comment: Yes, that's because of historical reasons...  try filing a bug at the FSF and they'll tell you: "Some scripts might use this "feature" and we keep it for backward compatibility"... It's outdated now, but guess what this will look like in 25 years... ;)

Comment: Maybe you are also expert on SSD usage and care to comment on my other question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/572168/which-parts-of-ubuntu-would-you-place-on-ssd-and-not-hdd-to-leverage-better-sy

Comment: @Rinzwind gave you a better answer I would have given, but I download huge torrent files so I keep my `/tmp` on my SSD which is much larger then my RAM (only 4GB)...