# I want to move /run/shm to my /home directory

Tags: partitioning, filesystem

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       9.1G  8.4G  214M  98% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.9G  8.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           390M  1.2M  389M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G  8.8M  1.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   52K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda4       1.9G   89M  1.7G   6% /boot
/dev/sda7        54G  6.5G   45G  13% /home
/dev/sda2       274G  166G  109G  61% /media/ubuntu/74386C84386C46E8
/dev/sda5       355G  337G   19G  95% /media/ubuntu/Nouveau nom
```

I have not enough space in my `/` directory and want to move `/run/shm` at my `/home`.

Comment: That's a REALLY wierd partition layout, and fairly badly planned. There's little reason to split off non critical OS stuff (or for that matter anything but /home and maybe /etc). IMO splitting up a system into different mountpoints is really a relic of tiny old drives.

Answer (score 3):

Please read [What are "/run/lock" and "/run/shm" used for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169495/what-are-run-lock-and-run-shm-used-for) and see why what you are asking is not possible and not going to help you create space on `/` and that you are incorrectly interpreting this data: `/run/*/` is a `tmpfs`; not actual space. Then `none` in the file system column indicates this is not an actual hard disk. You need to analyse why / is 8.4Gb.

---

I would advise you to ...

- check your log files. On a desktop 8.4 GB is a lot. For a server the 9.1 is not enough. I have a desktop version with MySQL (so technically it is a server) running and some test databases for data analyses. My root stays around 10Gb and 15Gb so I would advise a 20Gb if you use this as a server too. But if this is a normal desktop system there might be some log files that contain errors and grow. Fix the error, delete the old logs and you will have more free space in `/`.
- merge `/` and `/home`. There is not really any reason any more to have a separate `/home`. During installation you can nowadays opt to keep your current documents. If you do not want to merge you can also opt to shrink `/home` and add the unallocated space to `/`. Both can be done from an Ubuntu Live DVD with gParted installed or a [gParted Live DVD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php).